# uinavigationcontroller and landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

Does uinavigationcontroller support landscape view?  Meaning that I want the bar to appear at the top of the iphone and for the view to be fat.. like 480px

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. But you need to support that orientation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In your `UIViewController` that you want to support multiple orientation mode.

Implements the following function to indicates that you want to support (both) landscape mode and only the normal portrait mode. (The most common setup)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    switch (interfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait: {
            return YES;
        } break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        default: {
            return NO;
        } break;
    }
}
```

The `UINavigationController` will follows the current `UIViewController` orientation setup and react accordingly.